# Phonegap splashscreen disappears automaticly

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

My phonegap app shows a splashscreen before showing you the "index.html"... But whatever I do, whatever timeout I set it just ignores it and shows the splash for less than half a second... I like the fact that the app loads fast but showing the splash for so little time defeats the whole purpose...

I've tried to put a delay in like this  `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 5000);`  with no luck... nothing...just ignores it...

Then I tried this https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/doc/index.md

Set the preference:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
```

Again nothing. Its driving me crazy.... Any ideas?
I can post more code too....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add thi to your `config.xml`

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
//So splashscreen won't be hidden automatically.
```

Add this to your `index.html`:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 2000);
}
```

This will hide the splashscreen 2 seconds after the onDeviceReady event.
You can change `2000` milliseconds to whatever you want.

Comment: Even without the splashscreen.hide() the splash still disappears in less than a second... I have no idea why

Comment: Okay I just noticed that I have 2 config.xml files... One is in assets folder and one in res/xml folder... Why and which one do I need to edit

Comment: You need the one in the `res/xml` folder

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change value of 'SplashScreenDelay' in config.xml.

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" /> <!-- this will add 3000 ms delay -->
```

If its not working then try remove and add platform again using:

```
cordova platform rm platform-name
cordova platform add platform-name
```